# Clicking on Gtk apps menu bar kills mouse

Tags: gnome, mouse, gtk, awesome

I'm using the following configuration:

- Ubuntu 11.10 x64
- Awesome Window Manager v3.4.10
- Gnome 3.2

...and I got the following problem:

[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

**Every time I click on the empty space in a menubar or toolbar in a Gtk application (like Nautilus, GEdit), mouse clicks don't work any more.** Sometimes it also happens after clicking a resize grip ([See this bug report](http://osdir.com/ml/blfs-support/2011-12/msg00059.html)).

I'm still able to move the mouse cursor, but clicking and scrolling doesn't have any effect.

All keyboard actions work as before, e.g. I can switch desktops with Mod4-Left / Mod4-Right, type in text boxes or switch the active window with Mod4-j/k.

When I close the application where I did the killing click, everything works perfectly as before.

This is especially annoying when it happened in Nautilus as I have to `killall nautilus` to make it work again, which kills the desktop as well.

Does anybody have the same problem, and is there any bugfix around?

---

**EDIT**

I found this [item in the Ubuntu Bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/878859) which describes exactly this misbehavior. As far as I understand, they want to release the bugfix in the next Ubuntu version, 12.04. Is there a chance to get the update earlier? Do I have to compile Gtk myself, if yes, how to do this?

---

*Note: I asked this, less specific, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33980/mouse-clicks-stop-working-after-random-time-using-awesome-wm-gnome)*

Comment: Okay, I found some more information and changed my question a bit.