# Linux Mint Mouse Stops working, seemingly when touching the edge of a GTK window

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, gtk

Linux Mint Mouse Stops working, seemingly when touching the edge of a GTK window. This has been working fine for some time, no updates were installed that could have caused it. All similar issues I've been able to find are attached to bugs marked as Resolved.

It seems similar in nature to this issue:
[Mouse clicks stop working after random time, using Awesome WM + Gnome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33980/mouse-clicks-stop-working-after-random-time-using-awesome-wm-gnome)

Restarting metacity gets the machine in a tizzy if you do it too many times and it only fixes the problem as far as it happening again 2 seconds later when you use the mouse again.

Anyone experiencing this issue or can advise on how to debug?

Comment: Detail, details. Versions involved, hardware, ...

Comment: Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon x64, Logitech MX Laser; http://img.tomshardware.com/us/2004/09/24/the_logitech_mouse_goes_laser/mx1000-2.jpg as I said this has worked fine for over a year and has suddenly decided to stop working.